How should I unwrap this table leg?
I'm somewhat new to Blender, and am trying to render a table. I've run into issues with this table leg's texturing. I can't seem to unwrap it properly. I exported the table design from Fusion 360, so it has a ton of faces. What would be the best way to unwrap it so the texture lines up correctly?
Current Issue:
I've tried unwrapping it, but the issue I keep running into is the grain gets broken. Instead of it being vertical around the entire object, it is vertical on maybe 2 sides, then broken on the other 2. I've tried using the cylinder uv unwrap, but that makes the grain/texture spiraled.




Try adding a seam down one side of the leg, as well as ones on the smaller loops and bumped parts. You should be able to unwrap the leg more cleanly with that.

So is this a wood image texture or a procedural texture? I cannot see what is so wrong about it... apart from the grain on the front face at the top running in the same direction as the one to the left, which looks unnatural.

@GordonBrinkmann thats what is issue is. The grain pattern looks unnatural because of the way Blender unwraps the UV mapping of the object. The texture is a PBR image texture.

Well, as I said, only the top front face looks unnatural to me. The problem is, a texture is like a thin slice out of a piece of wood, basically 2-dimensional. A table leg is a 3-dimensional piece carved out of a wood block or trunk with a wood lathe and/or saw, and if you look at the corner of two orthogonal faces, only one of them could correctly show the 2-dimensional texture, while the orthogonal face would need a texture adding the third dimension to it. So no matter how good the UV unwrapping is, you will always have to somehow tweak it to make it look reasonable.
